# How to pass API_KEY through HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, curl

I'm trying to send `curl` request passing some headers and authentication info.

All information i want to send went successfully but I'm stuck with how to send the api key that should be used instead of the normal username/password manner.

when I use online `curl` websites to send the `curl` request, I put `:` after the api key and then everything works perfectly.

And this is what i want to do in C# using `HttpWebRequest`

This is the code I'm using in order to do that:

```
string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", "API_KEY", "GivenApiKey: ");
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials);
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        string authorization = String.Concat("Basic ", base64);
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.website.com/test");
        httpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000; 
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "GivenUserAgent";
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Authorization", authorization);
```

please any help?

Comment: Adding credentials to the API Request the way the you are doing will result in a basic auth header. Add the Auth header you want manually, as in @Hespen's response below.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the Authorization in a Header so:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + apikey;
```

Depending on the server you are contacting, you'll have to determine the input. In my case Bearer should be placed before the apikey. 
As most servers use the following setup for authorization:

```
Authorization: <type> <credentials>
```

Comment: Thanks dear, ok this solutions solved my authorization issue, but it ran me into another error which is: `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`

Comment: A 500 Error means that your codes works fine, the server is just having some issues. Do you keep the user agent as 'GivenUserAgent'? Try replacing it with something like `request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";` You could also try to perform the webrequest with Postman, to see if you get the same error.

Comment: Actually no I'm passing a specific API_KEY given by my client, but for privacy purposes I typed fake info